# Using Powershell and regex to split the string

Tags: regex, powershell

Using Powershell and regex. I need some help in splitting the following string.

```
arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:123456789012:targetgroup/AB-EXCHA/10a0497e85a88b21
```

All I need is the following from the above string
`targetgroup/AB-EXCHA/10a0497e85a88b21`

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Have a look at the `split` command. You could split on `:` and get the last element of the returned array to get your desired string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never did anything with powershell, but this prints the string you want:

```
$matches = "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:123456789012:targetgroup/AB-EXCHA/10a0497e85a88b21" | Select-String -pattern "(targetgroup.*)"
$($matches.matches.groups[1]).value
```

Result:

```
targetgroup/AB-EXCHA/10a0497e85a88b21
```